# World Background in Blender Internal Viewport

Tags: 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine

I've created a shader that works using the Blender Internal Viewport. I thought I would take advantage of the recently added "World Background" option in the 3D view so I could get a nice background for my 3d model and shader.

But when I check the option it doesn't replace the background with the Environment Map I have set in the World. instead it just set it to the Horizon Color. But I overrided the Horizion color in the texture options.

Is this feature not supported in BI or do I need to do something different?

Comment: What viewport shading are you using?  and are you in orthogonal or perspective view?

Comment: @Denis I've tried all shading views and both ortho and persp